# /proc/sys/net...　リンクアップ確認

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian

大変漠然とした質問で恐縮なのですが、
只今Raspberry Pi3(OS:Raspbian 8.0)でネットワーク周りのステータスを調べています。
有線NICであるeth0が使用可能になった際、
どこのディレクトリの値が変化するのか...というのが質問の内容です。

/proc/sys/netあたりを参照していますが、いまいちピンと来ていません。
このあたりではないかという意見をいただければ幸いです。
ご教授よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 迅速なご回答ありがとうございます。
/proc/net/devのご回答が自分のイメージと合致しました。
漠然とした質問でしたが、皆様丁寧なご回答をありがとうございました。

Answer (score 1):

敢えて`/proc`以下で確認をしたいという事であれば、`/proc/net/dev`にNIC毎の転送量が記録されているので、こちらの数値を参照するというのはどうでしょうか。

```
> cat /proc/net/dev
Inter-|   Receive                                                |  Transmit
 face |bytes    packets errs drop fifo frame compressed multicast|bytes    packets errs drop fifo colls carrier compressed
    lo:    2530     142    0    0    0     0          0         0     2530     142    0    0    0     0       0          0
  eth0:    4730     118    0   33    0    12          0        48     2883      11    0    0    0     0       0          0
  eth1:       0       0    0    0    0     0          0         0        0       0    0    0    0     0       0          0
```

Answer (score 0):

このコマンドで何か返って来ればeth0デバイスがUPと言うことになります。

```
ip link show eth0 up
```